# Excel 2010,I created template xltx 4 sheet/ book and Excel opens in Page Layout view only

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Excel 2010,I created template xltx 4 sheet/ book and Excel opens in Page Layout view only

I created a book.xltx and sheet.xltx that simply opens up Excel with a footer that has Page # on one line and the next footer line has the File Path.

When I open up Excel while it does have the correct footer it opens up the new blank spreadsheet in Page Layout view and not Normal View.

I re-saved the templates and same thing--opened up in Page Layout view.

I deleted the templates and recreated and same thing happened.

It is just a nit and I can simply click on Normal view but was hoping there was a solution.

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's related to your templates but rather a setting of Excel itself. Can you check what is the value of this setting: `File` -> `Options` -> `General` -> `Default view type for new workbooks`? (I'm translating from my localized version of Excel so the wording might not be exact)